# How to select a value in mongodb aggregate query whose key name is in value

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, aggregate

I have data like below

```
 {
    "_id": "5de23837d7231325d0e3f9ad",
        "status": "cancelled",
        "createdAt": "2019-11-30T09:36:09.712Z",
        "user": "5d73677739be3a2340870dd2",
        "platform": "ios",
        "products": {
          "discount": 88,
          "_id": "5de23811014f0209345b54ef",
          "roomArrangement": [],
          "category": "adventure",
          "adventure": {
            "title": "This is high1",
            "location": {
              "code": "code",
              "name": "Manali",
              "state": {
                "code": "123",
                "name": "state",
                "slug": "state"
              }
         }
 }
```

Now I want select a key whose value is category. In above example category = "adventrue" then select adventrue category. Means I need to select products.adventure but adventure is a dynamic key which I will get from category. Please suggest me how to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $addFields: { product_data: { $objectToArray: "$products" } } },
   { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$products.category", "$product_data.k"] } } },
   { $unset: "product_data" }
])
```